# How to scroll a div's content when the cursor is outside of this div using jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As on my question title, i want to allow users to scroll the content inside a div even when their mouse pointer is outside of the div with id="scrolldiv". Here is a quick mockup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxFOS.jpg

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402766/scroll-a-div-from-everywhere so it would be great if a moderator could close this question as duplicated. Thanks so much.

Comment: @stack fan i already mentioned it on my comment.

Comment: yep. now this question will be closed by someone

Comment: ok i did it by my self ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [This jQuery Library](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) alongside standard jQuery.
Code would be like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>/*!
 * jQuery Mousewheel 3.1.13
 *
 * Copyright 2015 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a:a(jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var g=b||window.event,h=i.call(arguments,1),j=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0;if(b=a.event.fix(g),b.type="mousewheel","detail"in g&&(m=-1*g.detail),"wheelDelta"in g&&(m=g.wheelDelta),"wheelDeltaY"in g&&(m=g.wheelDeltaY),"wheelDeltaX"in g&&(l=-1*g.wheelDeltaX),"axis"in g&&g.axis===g.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(l=-1*m,m=0),j=0===m?l:m,"deltaY"in g&&(m=-1*g.deltaY,j=m),"deltaX"in g&&(l=g.deltaX,0===m&&(j=-1*l)),0!==m||0!==l){if(1===g.deltaMode){var q=a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height");j*=q,m*=q,l*=q}else if(2===g.deltaMode){var r=a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height");j*=r,m*=r,l*=r}if(n=Math.max(Math.abs(m),Math.abs(l)),(!f||f>n)&&(f=n,d(g,n)&&(f/=40)),d(g,n)&&(j/=40,l/=40,m/=40),j=Math[j>=1?"floor":"ceil"](j/f),l=Math[l>=1?"floor":"ceil"](l/f),m=Math[m>=1?"floor":"ceil"](m/f),k.settings.normalizeOffset&&this.getBoundingClientRect){var s=this.getBoundingClientRect();o=b.clientX-s.left,p=b.clientY-s.top}return b.deltaX=l,b.deltaY=m,b.deltaFactor=f,b.offsetX=o,b.offsetY=p,b.deltaMode=0,h.unshift(b,j,l,m),e&&clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(c,200),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,h)}}function c(){f=null}function d(a,b){return k.settings.adjustOldDeltas&&"mousewheel"===a.type&&b%120===0}var e,f,g=["wheel","mousewheel","DOMMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],h="onwheel"in document||document.documentMode>=9?["wheel"]:["mousewheel","DomMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],i=Array.prototype.slice;if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var j=g.length;j;)a.event.fixHooks[g[--j]]=a.event.mouseHooks;var k=a.event.special.mousewheel={version:"3.1.12",setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.addEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=b;a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height",k.getLineHeight(this)),a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height",k.getPageHeight(this))},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.removeEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null;a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-line-height"),a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-page-height")},getLineHeight:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c["offsetParent"in a.fn?"offsetParent":"parent"]();return d.length||(d=a("body")),parseInt(d.css("fontSize"),10)||parseInt(c.css("fontSize"),10)||16},getPageHeight:function(b){return a(b).height()},settings:{adjustOldDeltas:!0,normalizeOffset:!0}};a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})});</script>
</head>
<body><div id='contentDiv' style='max-height:100px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:scroll;' height='250'><img src="https://i.imgur.com/cMfn7tk.png"/></div>
<script>
$(function() {
    var $target = $('#contentDiv');
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      $target.scrollTop($target.scrollTop() - (delta * 30));
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above will work as a standalone, I placed the entire jQuery mousewheel library within  tags, so you should either find a CDN or host it locally to clean the whole thing up a bit better. Source for this answer (credits): [FlabbyRabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402766/scroll-a-div-from-everywhere)

Comment: Ahh I didn't see your comment saying that you found the answer in that link. That's what I was sourcing mine from too.